# Want to create a new variable based the parts of another

Tags: r

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I7gZE.jpg)

Hi!

I would like to extract partial information from the variable wave_year (added picture of my dataframe). It consists of wave followed by year (4 digits). I would like to keep only the digit(s) before the year. Is there a simple way to remove the 4 last number?

Appreciate any pointers! Thanks

Thank you very much for all feedback. Really appreciate it!

Comment: Don't add code or data as images. Help others getting your sample data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `str_sub`

```
df %>% 
  mutate(wave_year=str_sub(wave_year, end=-5)) %>% 
  type.convert(as.is = TRUE)
```

Output:

```
   wave_year     swb  year
       <int>   <dbl> <int>
 1         8 -1.99    1998
 2         8 -0.809   2002
 3        12  0.685   2002
 4        12  1.25    2014
 5        20  2.65    2005
 6        20  3.26    2018
 7        31  0.0744  1997
 8        31  1.89    2011
 9        32  1.76    1984
10        32  2.45    1991
11        32  2.19    1995
12        32  2.62    1999
13        32  3.19    2006
14        32  2.95    2013
15        32  3.20    2017
```

data:

```
df <- tibble::tribble(
  ~wave_year,      ~swb, ~`year`,
        81998L, -1.98976293,     1998L,
        82002L, -0.80897704,     2002L,
       122002L,  0.68499127,     2002L,
       122014L,  1.24977085,     2014L,
       202005L,  2.64959839,     2005L,
       202018L,  3.26147705,     2018L,
       311997L,  0.07441608,     1997L,
       312011L,  1.88522954,     2011L,
       321984L,  1.76248548,     1984L,
       321991L,  2.45132275,     1991L,
       321995L,  2.19036027,     1995L,
       321999L,  2.61647255,     1999L,
       322006L,   3.1884984,     2006L,
       322013L,  2.95206862,     2013L,
       322017L,  3.19507187,     2017L
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `gsub`.

```
gsub('(.*)\\d\\d\\d\\d$', '\\1', df$wave_year)
```

To clarify the meaning: `(.*)` is capturing everything at the beginning and saving it as `\\1` and `\\d\\d\\d\\d$` is capturing the last four digits.

Comment: `sub` suffices as there's just one match per string

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your dataframe is called `df`, this `sub`transformation using backshift `\\1` should work:

```
df$wave_year <- sub("(.*)(\\d{4})$", "\\1", df$wave_year)
```